# Can't compile libcgcrypt-1.6.1 - can't see libgpg-error

Tags: c, compilation

```
[...]
checking for GPG Error - version >= 1.11... no
configure: error: libgpg-error is needed.
                See ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/ .

Username@Computername /cygdrive/f/coding/sourcecode/libgcrypt-1.6.1
$ gpg-error-config --version
1.9
```

As you can see I do have gpg-error installed, or so it seems.
Perhaps the problem is that the source directory is on F:\ while Cygwin, Windows and everything else are on C:\?

I've found the same question asked before on http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2009-May/036486.html -- unanswered...

Cygwin 1.7.31, Windows 8.1 x64, libgcrypt-1.6.1 and libgpg-error is 1.9, naturally.

Thank you in advance, please tell me if I should provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the silly question; it appears I hadn't set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH correctly. If you are having a similar problem, it is worth checking your CPATH and PATH as well, while you're at it.

If you're using Cygwin like me, be sure to add -

- */usr/local/lib* to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH,
- */usr/local/include* to CPATH,
- */bin* and */usr/bin* to PATH (and put those before .../windows/system32).

After that everything should install.